# How do i get information from a slider using button in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I get the following error AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'GetValue'
I'm running Python 3.9.13

```
import wx
import os
style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER
class main(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self,parent,id) :
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Slider", size=(500,300),style=style)
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        button=wx.Button(panel,label="Work!", pos=(90,90), size=(100,100))
        slider= wx.Slider(panel, value=1, minValue=1, maxValue=255, style= wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS, pos=(200,90), size=(250,60))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.val, button,slider)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closewindow)
        self.Center() 
    def val(self,event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject() 
        val = obj.GetValue() 
        print(val)
    def closewindow(self,windows):
        self.Destroy()



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=main(parent=None,id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
You just need to add glboal value!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from logging.config import valid_ident
import wx
import os
global val
val = 1
style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER
class main(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self,parent,id) :
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Slider", size=(500,300),style=style)
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        button=wx.Button(panel,label="Work!", pos=(90,90), size=(100,100))
        slider= wx.Slider(panel, value=1, minValue=1, maxValue=255, style= wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS, pos=(200,90), size=(250,60))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, button,)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, slider, self.val)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closewindow)
        self.Center() 
    def val(self,event):
        global val
        obj = event.GetEventObject() 
        val = obj.GetValue() 
        print(val)
    def closewindow(self,windows):
        self.Destroy()



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=main(parent=None,id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dip into using `globals`, there are easier ways to get what you want, by binding to widgets that are declared as instance variables i.e. `self.something` and then binding to that. You are, after all declaring `self` in each `def`, before the `event`.
In this way, you do not have to quiz the event object, instead you can directly access the widget by name.

e.g. (Your code amended slightly)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx

style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER

class main(wx.Frame) :
    def __init__(self,parent,id) :
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Slider", size=(500,300),style=style)
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.button=wx.Button(panel,label="Work!", pos=(90,90), size=(100,100))
        self.slider= wx.Slider(panel, value=1, minValue=1, maxValue=255, style= wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS, pos=(200,90), size=(250,60))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onbutton,)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closewindow)
        self.Center() 

    def Onbutton(self,event):
        print("Button Pressed")
        val = self.slider.GetValue() 
        print("Slider value is : ", val)

    def closewindow(self,windows):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=main(parent=None,id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```